# Footnotes in xltabular

Tags: tables, footnotes, xltabular

I'm working on my LaTeX template, so I searched some table packages and I found `xltabular` the perfect one, as I can combine `tabularx` and `longtable` and still being able to use `tabularx` without `longtable`. Unfortunately `xltabular` is a great option but with a catch, footnotes don't work properly. I searched alternative solutions but none of them combined those 2 packages I was looking for.

## Problem

The main problem is that in the environment `xltabular` the footnotes are always in the last page of the table, this might not seem as a huge problem until those footnotes cover a full blank page in the case that the table fits perfectly in its last page. I tried to found the problem but I found out that is weirder than I thought, in the case that all the cells are `X`, the footnotes appear in the page which were mentioned, but if at least one cell is not `X`, the problem of the footnotes appear.

## Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|c|X|X|}
\hline 1 & 2\footnote{THIS FOOTNOTE SHOULD APPEAR IN THE FIRST PAGE!} & 3 & When I met you in a summer, (summer) to my heart been sound \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `hyperref` package is just to link the footnotes.

Comment: you should put the footnote in a cell of type `p{..}` (X columns are of this type).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting, why does this work? It seems somehow unrelated at first sight.

Comment: @JasperHabicht see footnote 2 in the longtable documentation

Answer (score 1):

I'm of the same opinion as [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)  just put your note in `p{..}`

The code bellow :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|p{0.6cm}|X|X|}
\hline 1 & 2\footnote{ FOOTNOTE 1 } & 3 & When I met you in a summer, (summer) to my heart been sound \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3\footnote{ FOOTNOTE 2 } & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2\footnote{ FOOTNOTE 3 } & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\footnote{ FOOTNOTE 4 } \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\\\hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm interested to use the column type `c` and `X` while having footnotes, so is there any column type or any way to use `c` while not having this footnote error?